# Schedule events in Linux without cron

Tags: linux, cron, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

Currently I schedule events in MacOS with launchd using a script with Plistbuddy to write to plist files
to update dates and times. Note: cron has been deprecated in MacOS .

Can I get some advice on what methods can be used in Linux to reliably schedule events without using cron.
I want to do one off as well as recurring events. Also run at startup. By events I mean start apps and run scripts.

I know I can use 'cron' for recurring events and 'at' for one off events. But I like launchd in MacOS. So I prefer to use a single method which can run all requirements such as startup, one time only or reocurring. Just curious about alternatives.

Comment: Which Linux? Does it have systemd? Why do you want to avoid cron?

Comment: Ubuntu or Fedora. Both have systemd. I know I can use 'cron' for recurring events and 'at' for one off events. But I like launchd in MacOS I prefer to use a single method which can run all requirements such as startup, one time only or recurring.

Comment: [Google is your friend](http://blog.higgsboson.tk/2013/06/09/use-systemd-as-a-cron-replacement/)

Comment: Haha. What's the point of this forum then? If you search Google you often get directed back to here.